# htaccess 301 issuing problem with sub-directory creating a 404

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404, subdirectory, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect an url that gives me an error 404.
I need to redirect 'website.com/example/sub-example' to 'website.com/example2'
Note that in my .htaccess file 'example2' already exists because is and url for another redirection, but every time I run the url 'website.com/example/sub-example' it jumps to 'website.com/example2/sub-example' and gives me an 404.
 I don't want the sub-directory on the redirect URL. 
Wish I was clear enough. And if anyone help me because I really don't know what to do.

If can help I'm using WP and this one below is my .htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: _"Note that in my .htaccess file 'example2' already exists"_ - not in what you have currently shown us. Please update your question, so that we can see what you are actually currently doing with your rewriting.

Comment: Hey @CBroe, I resolved it and updated the question. It was a simpler that I imagined. 
Thank you anyway, have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: I resolved it. Basically “example2” was at the top of my redirected item so every time I tried to run ‘website.com/example/sub-example’ it was running ‘website.com/example2/sub-example’and eventually that page doesn’t exist. I simply moved every redirect with more than one subfolder (or subdirectory) at the top of the redirected pages and everything seems to work.
So after 8h of work I understood that the redirection pages works like works sex… “Dominate” who is at the top.